# using jquery to disable the add to cart or wish list based on user location

Tags: jquery, cookies

So I have everything pretty much worked out I collect the users zip code, test it against an array of zip codes in the coverage area and if the user is in the service area show the cart and wish list if they aren't disable the cart button and allow wishlist only. I know how to do this but not how to make it stay with the session, Ex: if the user goes to a different page I need the cart to continue to be disabled. I know I need to use cookies or something, I feel like I'm close. Any little bit helps. Thanks...

```
    <script>
    var zipCodeArray = ["98001",
    "98002", "98003", "98004", "98005", "98006"]
     $("#zipCode").live('keyup', function(){
       var zipCode = $(this).val();
       if(zipCode.length >4){
         if($.inArray(zipCode, zipCodeArray) > -1){
          //display the hidden elements if zip is in list 
          $("#cart").css("display:block");
         }else{
           alert("We only service this area...but you can add to wish list         ");
           $("#button-cart","#or").css("display:none");
           //hide add to cart and the "- OR -" text.
         } 
       }
    });    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    //make this appear in colorbox
    <div class="zipCode">
    <form>
    <input id="zipCode" name="zipCode" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `on` since `live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and I prefer to listen to blur for performance.

### [demo](http://www.gameover.co.il/236799/input-cookie)

```
 $(window).load(function () {
var zipCodeArray = ["98001", "98002", "98003", "98004", "98005", "98006"];
//Get user cookie match zip and 5 digits only. Assign False if it doesn't
var userZip = document.cookie.match(/zip=(\d{5})/) || false;
//Cache #cart
var cart = $("#cart");
//Cache #zipCode
var input = $("#zipCode");
if (userZip) {
    input.val(userZip[1]);//Inject cookie value to input
    cart.show();//Show cart
}
input.on('blur', function () {
    //If userZip is defined use userZip
    var zipCode = userZip ? userZip[1] : $(this).val();
    console.log(zipCode);//Debugging
    //No need to check for input length
    if ($.inArray(zipCode, zipCodeArray) > -1) {
        console.log('in array');
        //display the hidden elements if zip is in list 
        cart.show();
        if (!userZip) {
            document.cookie = "zip=" + zipCode;//Save cookie
            console.log("cookie " + document.cookie);//Debugging
        }
    } else {
        alert("We only service this area...but you can add to wish list");
        $("#button-cart", "#or").css("display:none");
        //hide add to cart and the "- OR -" text.
    }
});
})
```

Comment: My website unfortunately uses 1.7, your code isn't working no matter what version of jquery I link to. Thanks though.

Comment: @user2570708 thanks for your input. It had a few problems. I've edited and added a demo.

Comment: Well that got large fast :) I'm interested to test this out. I find it easier to learn if I have something to dissect. Thank you, I'll be sure to mark it answered when I finish testing.